# javascript class method loading json file issue

Tags: javascript, json

I have a class setup below and things mostly work but when json.onjload is called I keep getting an error in console stating "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of 'push' of undefined`"

How do I fix this error?

```
var Clazz = new function(){
  this.library = [];

  this.add_library = function(file){
    var json = new XMLHttpRequest();
    json.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    json.open("GET", file, false); //needs to be synchronise
    json.onload = function(){
      this.library.push(JSON.parse(json.responseText));
      do something...
    };
    json.send(null);
  };
}

Clazz.add_library("path/file.json");
```

**Solution**

change `this.library.push(...);` to `Clazz.library.push(...);`

Comment: try  `Clazz.library.push(JSON.parse(json.responseText));`

Comment: not sure why I did not try that before, thanks @ÖzgürErsil

Comment: sometimes happen to everyone , happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Its because the scope changed inside `this.add_library`

```
var Clazz = new function(){
  this.library = [];
    var that = this;

  this.add_library = function(file){
    var json = new XMLHttpRequest();
    json.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    json.open("GET", file, false); //needs to be synchronise

    json.onload = function(){
        console.log(that)
      that.library.push(JSON.parse(json.responseText));
      //do something...
    };
    json.send(null);
  };
}

new Clazz.add_library("path/file.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var Clazz = new function(){
  this.library = [];

  this.add_library = (file) => {
    var json = new XMLHttpRequest();
    json.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    json.open("GET", file, false); //needs to be synchronise
    json.onload = () => {
      this.library.push(JSON.parse(json.responseText));
      do something...
    };
    json.send(null);
  };
}
```

or you must use the function `.bind(this)` since you have a problem with the visibility of `this` inside the function scope.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is with context. Basically JavaScript has several different cases for `this` and your example uses two of them:

1. Method invocation - `this` refers to the object that uses a method.
2. Function invocation - `this` referes to the global object or `undefined` in `strict mode`.

Let's see into your code (I will tweak your code a little for more clarification):

```
var Clazz = { // this code does the very same thing as `new function()`
    library: [], 

    add_library: function(file){ 
        // here if you use `this.library`, you would refer to the `library` field
        // and the code works perfectly fine, because `this` refers to the object Clazz
        json.onload = function(){
            this.library.push(JSON.parse(json.responseText));
            // ...on the other hand here `this` refers to the global object,
            // because `json.onload` is a function, even though it is inside a method `add_library`
        };
    };
}
```

How to fix this? There are several ways:

1. Use `.bind()`:

   ```
   json.onload = function(){
       this.library.push(JSON.parse(json.responseText));
   }.bind(Clazz);
   ```
2. Assign the context to a variable:

   ```
   const self = this;
   json.onload = function(){
       self.library.push(JSON.parse(json.responseText));
   }
   ```
3. Use arrow function:

   ```
   json.onload = () => {
       this.library.push(JSON.parse(json.responseText));
   }
   ```